# QImage::rgbSwapped() function works very slow

Tags: qt

I am displaying 2800x2200 image from camera with 15fps on Qt.

It sends data with BGR format, so I converted BGR format to RGB format by using QImage::rgbSwapped() function.

But it takes around 83ms on my PC, which lead to so much lagging.

I tried to use QGLWidget, and it works well, but it makes it slow another widgets, for example, split bar, slider bar and so on.

Is there any way to display BGR format directly or to speed up rgbSwapped() in Qt?

Comment: Are you using std::move? That will be faster, i.e. `std::move(image).rgbSwapped()`

Comment: I think the OpenGL approach is the most promising, I'd try to profile to find out why it slows down the UI so much (doing too much work for every frame?)

Comment: Yes, it is a bit heavy with around 20 widgets in a view.

Comment: Your choises are OpenGL shaders V.S. OpenCV. I doubt you can really write both fastest and cross-platform imlementation by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are big images, so they will always take some time, but you can speed up rgbSwapped by doing it on an rvalueref, like this:

```cpp
img = std::move(img).rgbSwapped();
```

One hack you can try if your input is RGB32, is using QImage::reinterpretAsFormat(QImage::RGBX8888). This will on little-endian architectures (x86 and modern ARM) do the same rgbSwapped(), but without touching a single pixels. The routines drawing it will be less optimized though :/

Finally rgbSwapped on formats other than RGB32 is greatly optimized in Qt 5.12 or 5.13 (can't remember where it landed)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) built in function, example:

```
QImage matToQImage(const cv::Mat &mat)
{
    if(mat.channels() == 1) { // if grayscale image
        return QImage((uchar*)mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, static_cast<int>(mat.step), QImage::Format_Grayscale8).copy();
    } 
    if(mat.channels() == 3) { // if 3 channel color image
        cv::Mat rgbMat;
        cv::cvtColor(mat, rgbMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB); // invert BGR to RGB
        return QImage((uchar*)rgbMat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, static_cast<int>(mat.step), QImage::Format_RGB888).copy();
    }
    return QImage();
}
```

Now it will work fast enough.

Comment: Well, actually, I just don't want to use OpenCV just for single function. :(

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use OpenCV for converting BGR to RGB? It works very fast than any other functions I know. If you don't want to use OpenCV, then why you put the opencv tag on your question?